# Using PHP & SQL Login Failed?

Tags: php, sql-server

I found problems dealing with the basic login page, however it did not display any login information here, and I am too new to PHP & SQL so can't fix it properly. Don't know where has missed:

```
 <?php

session_start();
include("require_pro.php");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
    $myusername=addslashes($_POST['username']);
    $mypassword=md5(addslashes($_POST['password']));

     $sql=" SELECT * FROM user 
            WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'

    ";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);



    if($count==1)
    {
        echo "Login Successfully";


    } 


}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html public "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang='en' xml:lang='en'>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=”text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
    </head>
<html>
<title>Login-In</title>
<body>
<fieldset style="border:2px groove; border-color:blue; padding:15px 30px 15px;margin-right:5px;width:350px;height:150px">
<form action="login1.php" method="post">
<p><b>User Name </b>  <input type="text" name="username" size="20px" maxlength="15"></p>
<p><b>Password  </b> <input type="password" name="password" size="20px" maxlength="15"></p>
<div align="left"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value=login></div>
</form>
</fieldset>
</body>
```

My require.php file:

```
<?php
$server="localhost";
$username="rgun";
$password="";
$database="rgun";

$dbc=@mysql_connect($server,$username,$mysql_user,$mysql_password) or die("Database connection failed");
mysql_select_db($database,$dbc) or die("Can't select the database");





?>
```

USER SQL:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qcmto7ol2fyv7y2/rgun.sql?dl=0&s=sl

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the database correctly? Can you post your code for that? edit - sorry i just saw it below.

Comment: mysql_connect($server,$username,$mysql_user,$mysql_password) is wrong. where you define $mysql_user and $mysql_password?

Comment: connection string should be:
sql_connect($server,$username,$password)

Answer (score 1):

There is issue in your connection string. your connection string should be:

```
<?php 
$server="localhost";
$username="rgun";
$password="";
$database="rgun";

$dbc=mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die("Database connection failed");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
    $myusername=addslashes($_POST['username']);
    $mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']);

  $sql=" SELECT * FROM user 
            WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);



    if($count == 1)
    {
        echo "Login Successfully";


    } 


}
```

I have update my code. there is also mistake that in your database your password is not saved in md5 but you are adding md5 like that

```
$mypassword=md5(addslashes($_POST['password']));
```

so remove md5 here or insert your password in md5 format in database, then your script will run. i have tested code that i posted in this answer, that execute perfect and gave desired result so try this code.

mysql_* are officially deprecated so use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: yeah, I tried your method but still does not work. What if you use mysqli ? How would that change ? and how to use the object-oriented method if PDO applies ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php  read here about mysqli so you can get idea about it.

Comment: @DerrickRuan i have updated my code implement that code you can get your result.

Comment: Oh yea !! You are amazing, @Raja Usman Mehmood, Thanks for the MD5 things, I think I need to work much harder on this,; )

Comment: yes. thanks, if your work is done then choose my answer is best if my answer deserve best.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with the code and database that you have shared.

1. Password Hashing is missing : You have stored password as not-encrypted/plain text.
2. Use of MD5 during variable assignment : You have used md5() function during "mypassword" variable assignment.

So,either you can update 'users' table and encrypt password via : UPDATE `USER` SET `password` = MD5(`password`);
OR, remove md5() function from mypassword variable assignment. From "$mypassword=md5(addslashes($_POST['password']));" to "$mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']);"

An word of caution :

1. Do not store password in plain text or non-encrypted manner.
2. "user", "password" etc are keywords in MySql, try not use those inside database/table schema.

Comment: happy to help fellow PHPmen :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what output you receive:

```
 session_start();
    include("require_pro.php");

    $myusername = addslashes($_POST['username']);
    $password = addslashes($_POST['password']);
    $mypassword = md5($password);


    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$myusername'and password ='$mypassword'") or die (mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($count == 1) {
        echo "Login Successfully";
    }
```